# Remove / Disable default custom.css?ver=1.0.0

Tags: css

On my front end on every single page, I have `custom.css?ver=1.0.0` loading. But it's not included anywhere in my custom-built theme.

At present, I am running `WordPress v6.1.1`.

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom-css' href='https://schoolarly.live/wp-content/themes/schoolarly/assets/css/custom.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Is this somehow loaded by default? If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: As you can see from the URL it’s loaded form your theme, so you’ll need to ask your theme author for assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could use the `wp_dequeue_style` function in a WordPress hook to unenqueue the custom-css stylesheet:

```
function wpsx411806_unenqueue_custom_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'custom-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsx411806_unenqueue_custom_css' );
```

In this example, the `wpsx411806_unenqueue_custom_css` function uses the `wp_dequeue_style` function to unenqueue the `custom-css` stylesheet. The function is then registered as a callback for the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.